# Bulk collect insert vs simple insert

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

There are two tables table_abc and table_xyz

`table_abc`:

```
EXPIRATION_DATE
ISSUE_DATE
ISSUING_AUTHORITY
ISSUING_COUNTRY
ISSUING_LOCATION
LEGISLATION_CODE
NUMBER
TYPE
```

`table_xyz`:

```
    EXPIRATION_DATE
    ISSUE_DATE
    ISSUING_AUTHORITY
    ISSUING_COUNTRY
    ISSUING_LOCATION
    LEGISLATION_CODE
    NUMBER
    TYPE
    PERSON_NO
```

Now I have to import all the data from table_abc to table_xyz

For this should I write this simple SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table_xyz
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_abc ;
```

or instead I tried to write a plsql procedure like follows :

```
Cursor cursor_abc

 SELECT * FROM table_abc;


  --PL/SQL Table to store the data temporarily
TYPE abc_tab_type
IS
  TABLE OF table_abc%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  abcTAB abc_tab_type;

  BULK_ERRORS EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (BULK_ERRORS, -24381);
BEGIN
   OPEN cursor_abc;
    LOOP
    FETCH cursor_abc BULK COLLECT INTO abcTAB ;

      FORALL I IN 1..abcTAB.COUNT
     INSERT
      INTO table_xyz
        (
         column names
        )
      SELECT column ames
      FROM table_abc


    EXIT WHEN CURSOR_abc%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CURSOR_abc;


END;
```

This code is throwing error on the lines of insert:

> PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL

I have to do this for 26 tables.. so i want a more performance optimized solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_xyz
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_abc ;
```

Will do the work for you provided the column orders and their data types are same. Or even you can do it when you create the table table_xyz.

Some thing like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_xyz AS
SELECT * from table_abc WHERE 1=1
;
```

Here first the table_xyz will be created with all column names from table_abc then the values from table_abc will be copied over to table_xyz